# Failed to find .env file at path: ./.env.local

Tags: reactjs, npm, node-modules

I am compiling my ReactJS app. It has already env.local file registered in the root:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WypnH.jpg)

However upon running npm start which executes "start": "env-cmd -f ./.env.local react-scripts start", below error occured:

Error: Failed to find .env file at path: ./.env.local
at getEnvFile (C:\Users\source\repos\SRPV\SRPV.Web\SRPV.Web\srpv-web\node_modules\env-cmd\dist\get-env-vars.js:40:19)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbCfz.png)

What else could go wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start the filename with a dot. "`.env`"

Comment: can u help me on https://stackoverflow.com/q/73944618/6097074